# UI system for web app?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a solid UI system for a new web app I'm working on.. By UI system I mean buttons, sliders, alert boxes... components overall.

I've checked bootstrap but I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for (I don't need a grid system).

I'm not sure if what I'm looking for is simply a "skinning" since it needs to hav functionality; but "skinning" as an addition could be nice (Like FlatUI for Bootstrap http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/)

I hope the question is clear.

Comment: The question is likely to be closed soon because these kinds of questions are too broad and ask primarily for subjective opinion. Search for "web UI components" using one of the major search engines, possibly adding "commercial" as an argument, and you will find quite a few.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)
- [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/)
- [ninjaui](http://ninjaui.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/)

Comprehensive HTML5/JavaScript framework for modern web and mobile app development

Kendo UI is everything professional developers need to build HTML5 sites and mobile apps. Today, productivity of an average HTML/jQuery developer is hampered by assembling a Frankenstein framework of disparate JavaScript libraries
and plug-ins.

Kendo UI has it all: rich jQuery-based widgets, a simple and consistent programming interface, a rock-solid DataSource, validation, internationalization, a MVVM framework, themes, templates and the list goes on.

WEB DEMOS are [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/overview/index.html)

Stackoverflow question are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kendo-ui) about Kendo UI